# How do I create an AWS VPC Endpoint for Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-elasticsearch

I have a lambda function which must be placed in a VPC because it communicates over a VPC peering connection. I also need it to upload to my Elasticsearch Service domain (not in a VPC because it is publicly accessible). But currently when Lambda tries to talk to ES, it times out.

I ran into this problem with Secrets Manager, so I went into the lambda's VPC, clicked on Endpoints, and created a Secrets Manager endpoint. I would like to do the same with Elasticsearch Service, but it doesn't show up in my list of AWS Services, which is odd because it definitely is an AWS Service.

Any idea how I can add an endpoint for Elasticsearch Service in my VPC so my Lambda function can talk to it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no VPC endpoint** for ES. The services that support the endpoints are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/integrated-services-vpce-list.html).

Regarding the timeout, you would have to provided detailed description of your VPC setup, subnets, route tables, lambda and explain how did you setup your ES and how do you try to access it from VPC. Its difficult to speculate why it times out without all the details.

But since your ES is public, one possibility could be because lambda in VPC will not be able to connect to it without the use of NAT gateway. By default, lambda in a VPC does not have internet connectivity.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping to avoid using a NAT gateway. I thought those were only for accessing the public internet? This is entirely within AWS. Would my traffic then flow out of VPC, into the public internet, then back into AWS somehow?

Comment: @JohnD. Yes it would. You either have to remove your function from the VPC, or you NAT.

Comment: Thanks. I will refactor my program to have part work behind the VPC, upload the results to S3, then have another function not in a VPC pull down the data and continue the operation.